# Exclude fields from FOSUserBundle using JMS Serializer working on dev but not on prod environment

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, jmsserializerbundle

I would like to exclude fields when exposing my API from my user class that extends FOSUser.

I've setup JMS Serializer on the global config file and created a FOSUB config to only expose the fields I need.

**Global Config:**

```
app/config/config.yml

jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        directories:
            FOSUB:
                namespace_prefix: "FOS\\UserBundle"
                path: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/serializer/fos"
```

**FOS config file:**

```
src/AppBundle/Resources/config/serializer/fos/Model.user.yml
FOS\UserBundle\Model\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            expose: true
        email:
            expose: true
        roles:
            expose: true
```

This config is working perfectly on my local machine however it doesn't work when deployed on prod. Both use same stack, my guess is that on prod somehow the serializer can't find FOS config file.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was somehow related to the naming of the config file.

While in local (macos) the file name `Model.user.yml` was working, in production (centos) it didn't work. So I had to rename the file to `Model.User.yml` then it worked fine on both.

I tried to find some documentation related to this issue but couldn't find any.

**Take away:** Make sure that the config file name represent **exactly** the entity you want to override.